# Emacs Prelude: how to disable smartparens for perl files?

Tags: emacs, emacs-prelude

I am using current Emacs & Prelude on OS X, with almost zero custom configuration. When working on perl files, smartparens interfere with cperl-mode and pressing "{" inserts "{}}" ( https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/issues/1062 ) . What is the right way to disable smartparens for perl files only in prelude?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `cperl-electric-parens` you can just disable `smartparens` inserting that pair in perl mode, eg. add to your perl configuration

```
(with-eval-after-load 'smartparens
  (sp-local-pair 'cperl-mode "{" nil :actions nil))
```